# How to sue Google?

Tags: google

I am in Canada

And I believe Google has over charged me for $250

I know this amount is too small but it is about the principle

Shall I go to the local tribunal and lodge a claim or dispute ?

Comment: Too small for what? Many jurisdictions have small-claims courts or procedures.

Answer (score 4):

### Have you approached Google?

Your contract with Google has a dispute resolution procedure (I’d link to the Canadian terms but I can’t find them). Generally a court will not entertain your claim unless and until you have followed the procedure you agreed to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Ontario's small claims guidance which should be fairly similar, if not identical, to the other Provinces

> **How to sue in small claims court**
>
> **Prepare a Plaintiff's Claim**
>
> The Plaintiff's Claim is the document you must complete to start a
> small claim against a person or business. This form will be filed with
> the court as well as delivered to each of the people or businesses you
> are suing.
>
> **1. Make sure you have the facts.**  You will need to write a short, clear summary of the events that took place and the reasons you think
> you are entitled to money or property.
>
> You need to know the legal name and address of the person or business
> you are suing to prepare and serve your claim, and to enforce a
> judgment if you are successful.
>
> Businesses registered in the past five years can be found using
> ServiceOntario's online business name search, registration and renewal
> service.
>
> **2. Gather your evidence.**  Consider what witnesses and documents (evidence) you have to support your case. If you do not have
> supporting documents (e.g. you entered into a verbal agreement) or
> witnesses, your claim may still be successful. If it is just your word
> against the other person's, it may be more difficult to prove your
> case.
>
> Examples of evidence to support your claim are:
>
> - a contract
> - a record of any payments
> - returned cheques
> - photographs of property damage
>
> The person or business you are suing will have a chance to present
> their version of events when they respond to your claim.
>
> **3. Know the time limitations.**  There may be a limit on how long you can wait before making a claim. In most cases, a claim can't be
> filed if more than two years has passed since the incident. If you're
> not sure what limitation period applies to your case, you should
> consult a lawyer. See the Limitations Act.
>
> 4. Use the above information to complete your Plaintiff's Claim form.  This is the document you will serve (deliver) to the defendant(s).
>
> **Choose a filing method**
>
> You can file your small claim online, in-person or by mail.

https://www.attorneygeneral.jus.gov.on.ca/english/courts/scc/

Comment: You pay the same application fee to **bring** a claim against Google like against anyone else. Expenses may be bigger further down the road, yes, but those won't be for _bringing_  but rather for winning or cutting losses.

Comment: @Greendrake noted and thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit it later to correct my poor use of terminology.

Answer (score -2):

Because of the [rule of law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law), the process for initiating a lawsuit against a multi-billion dollar corporation is no different to if it was your next door neighbour.

With $250 at stake, this would be done through a small claims court / disputes tribunal. Particular forms to fill, fees to pay and addresses to submit at will depend on your geo location and will be easily findable.